# Cannot access the JSON data correctly

Tags: python, python-requests

https://www.swarovski.com.tr/PhysicalStore/GetStoreJsonByCityId?cityId=183

I cannot access data from this site:

`{"Success":true,"Data":"[{\"id\":10,\"storeId\":\"\",\"storeName\":\"Swarovski Sankopark AVM\",\"storeLat\":\"37.063253000000\",\"storeLang\":\"37.361040099997\",\"storeAddress\":\"Sanko Park AVM Zemin Kat Sarigüllük Mah. Rafet Isitmen Cad. Şehitkamil/Gaziantep\",\"storePhone\":\"0 342 338 68 78\",\"storeEmail\":\"\",\"storeWorkHours\":\"10:00-20:00\",\"storeWorkHoursWeekend\":null,\"storeCover\":\"https://img-swarovski.mncdn.com/Content/Images/Thumbs/0036549.jpeg\",\"storesPhotos\":[\"https://via.placeholder.com/900x600.jpg?text=STORE+1+IMAGE+1\",\"https://via.placeholder.com/900x600.jpg?text=STORE+1+IMAGE+2\",\"https://via.placeholder.com/900x600.jpg?text=STORE+1+IMAGE+3\"],\"countryId\":77,\"cityId\":183}]"}`

Because of bold bracket `x[Data]` is `str` value when I tried this code:

```
import requests
import re

city_ids = {"ankara":"162","antalya":"163","aydın":"165","bursa":"172","izmir":"191","istanbul":"190","eskişehir":"182",
"gaziantep":"183",
"trabzon":"211", }

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}

for i in city_ids:
    #print(city_ids[i])
    req = requests.get("https://www.swarovski.com.tr/PhysicalStore/GetStoreJsonByCityId?cityId="+city_ids[i],headers=headers)
    data = req.json
    print(type(data["Data"]))
```

Output:

```
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
```

I am totally stuck...

Comment: data = req.json()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you need to parse the data body as json. 
You can do it with the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#module-json) library in python.

```
import requests
import re
import json

city_ids = {"ankara":"162","antalya":"163","aydın":"165","bursa":"172","izmir":"191","istanbul":"190","eskişehir":"182",
"gaziantep":"183",
"trabzon":"211", }

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}

for i in city_ids:
    req = requests.get("https://www.swarovski.com.tr/PhysicalStore/GetStoreJsonByCityId?cityId="+city_ids[i],headers=headers)
    data = req.json()
    parsed = json.loads(data["Data"])
    print(parsed)
```